# For Quick Replace In SSMS 2012, how can I make Replace All the default button or is there a keyboard shortcut to execute the Replace All button?

Tags: t-sql, replace, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the **Find and Replace** / **Quick Replace** window.

However, the default button is <kbd>Find Next</kbd>.

When you are doing a lot of replacing, it would help if the <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button was the default.  To have to <kbd>TAB</kbd> all the way to <kbd>Replace All</kbd> from the **Replace With** box or to take your hands away from the keyboard to use the mouse to click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> wastes a *lot* of time.

***Is there a way to make*** <kbd>Replace All</kbd> ***the default button?***

***If not, I was wondering is there a keyboard shortcut to execute the*** <kbd>Replace All</kbd> ***button?***

Comment: What are you doing that you have to do a lot of find and replaces?  So many that you want to speed it up by changing the standard functionality?  Sorry, this is all you have: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx

Comment: Not that it's really pertinent to the question, but if you must know, I'm going through [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) and copying each country's subdivisions into SSMS and creating **INSERT** statements to put them into a **CountrySubdivision** table that we are going to be using here at work.  I'm only at the beginning of H and I have almost 3,000 lines of code.  So ... yes, it would be _extremely_ useful to have an answer to this question =D

Comment: **I** would copy the table (from the website) into Excel and `concatenate("INSERT INTO.. .. VALUES ('",A1,"');")`

Comment: Doesn't really work that way.  Some subdivisions have parent subdivisions and require a slightly different insert statement.  Not to mention, I'm creating a script that can be saved for re-creation/re-insertion if the table/data is lost for whatever reason.  Regardless, this doesn't really pertain to the question.  The question stands on its own as you could have a huge DTS package or script that requires multiple concurrent replaces based on different factors.

Comment: You would end up with that too by concatenating in Excel.  However if each insert statement is slightly different, then I'm not sure how you can automate it.  Ultimately there is nothing built into SSMS to do what you'd like.  Maybe something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would help?

Comment: Still a useful question — oddly, in SSMS 2014 the alt-key underlines are missing from the buttons until you tab through them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As **@DanAndrews** mentioned in the comments, it seems as there is no way other than using a 3rd party tool like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com). So that's what I did.

Here is the hotkey script I used:

```
>^>+Enter::
Click 1513, 505
return
```

This hotkey script is mapped to the key combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Once triggered, it will mimic a **Mouse Click** on the <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button inside of the **Find and Replace** window in **SSMS 2012**.

The **1513**, **505** mouse position is based on a **1600** x **1200** screen resolution and when the **Find and Replace** window is docked to the right hand side of **SSMS 2012**.

Answer (score 1):

I always use ALT+a, works all the time, where ever the window may be..

Comment: This works for me even in SSMS 2012. Maybe it was included in a minor update that OP was missing?